# Причастный оборот - запятая?

Tags: причастный-оборот

Нужно ли обособить запятыми "хоть немного имеющий смысл"?

> Единственный хоть немного имеющий смысл диалог.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не нужно, т. к. этот причастный оборот стоит перед определяемым словом.

UPD: Постановка запятой, если быть конкретней, зависит от смысла.

Если подчеркивается, что только этот диалог имеет смысл (следовательно, здесь два однородных определения), то запятую нужно поставить. Если же имеется в виду, что этот диалог *хотя бы* чуть-чуть имеет смысл, то запятой быть не должно, так как здесь два разнородных определения (и они не подводятся под одно понятие), запятой между которыми быть не должно.

Обратите внимание на ответ Справочной: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=291419.

Answer (score 2):

**Попробуем поставить запятую**: **Единственный, хоть немного имеющий смысл** диалог.

**Обоснование:** [Лопатин. Знаки препинания при однородных определениях](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114), § 38.

**Вот пример с запятой**: Единственный, хоть как-то меня оправдывающий довод ― то, что я уже третий день гриппую, всерьез, даже на работу не хожу. [Юлий Даниэль. Письма из заключения (1966-1970)]

Причастный оборот стоит между прилагательным и существительным, да еще имеет частицу ХОТЬ.

**Но:** единственный осмысленный диалог, единственный оправдывающий довод (неоднородные определения).

Comment: А по-моему, "единственный, хоть как-то меня оправдывающий довод" (из примера) - это вообще единственный довод, который можно было привести, и он же – оправдывающий. Потому и запятая. А "единственный хоть немного имеющий смысл диалог" - это единственный из диалогов, который имеет хоть немного смысла. Поэтому "единственный хоть немного имеющий смысл"  разрывать запятой нельзя.

Comment: Это формальная конструкция (причастный оборот между прилагательным и существительным). Сравнить: Единственный диалог, хоть немного имеющий смысл. Здесь тоже признаки разделены. Содержание двух записей одно и то же.